# MEANING OF A SENTENCE IN A E-MAIL

Tags: phrase-meaning

I want to know meaning of a sentence.the sentence meaning which I want to know is 
"there is no action from your side".

Comment: Why so loud? :)

Comment: Please note that "in an email" doesn't provide sufficient ***context*** to say exactly what the writer means. The cited text probably isn't something a competent writer would use in anything like a formal context, but we don't really have enough to go on here.

Comment: Much more context is needed.  It could mean you don't need to do anything.  It could mean that they are upset that you haven't done anything.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning I take is this:
"You do not need to take any action. I am providing this to keep you informed."

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: I think they're saying that you/your team isn't doing anything about the situation, whatever that may be.

Maybe they want you to contribute more?

EDIT: Maybe they're trying to tell you that it's okay that you're not doing anything to help.

Comment: I think if inaction was okay, then they’d say "There is no action *required* on your side*", but as your edit and comments above suggest, more context is necessary.

Comment: Right. Whoever was responsible for the message probably wanted the OP to act, as if the fact that he wasn't doing anything is a problem.